# Theory behind designing a html editor preview feature

Tags: javascript, ajax, editor, wysiwyg

Can someone describe and a high level (with detail ofcourse) how one goes about designing a html editor preview feature?

(like on this site)

What do you have to do really?

Answer (score 5):

Well, a very simple one might just assign the user's input to the be the HTML of a `div`.  Using jQuery, this would look something like this:

```
<textarea id="userInput"></textarea><br>
<div id="previewDiv"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Whenever the user input changes, update the preview
   $("#userInput").change(function(){
      $("#previewDiv").html($("#userInput").val());
   }
}
</script>
```

If you aren't using jQuery, you can investigate the [`innerHTML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533897(VS.85).aspx) property, that is what you would assign to do your preview.

Note that you may want to do some filtering of the user's input; serving arbitrary HTML from your site would allow XSS (cross site scripting) against your domain.  Note that writing an effective filter can be very difficult, and a good one (like the one used by stackoverflow) will almost certainly be based on a white-list.